# How do we prevent calling the method programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

We need to prevent a method call programmatically. We just want to call method with user interaction from `UI`.

Actually, We're developing a SDK. We have some custom UI object classes. We want to avoid the user access to target methods without using our custom UI objects.

`UIButton` is just an example. It can be `UISwitch` or another UI element. Or maybe `SwiftUI` elements.

This is required as a security measure. It is a precaution we want to put so that malicious people do not call it as if it is an operation from the interface.

We want the operation to be performed only from the interface. So we check the information in `Thread.callStackSymbols`. But this code doesn't work in Testflight or release. It only works in debug mode.

You will see a `UIButton` below example. When clicked it’ll call `clickedButton`. But there is a method that call `maliciousMethod`. It can call `clickedButton` programmatically. We want to prevent it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton) {
        /// We need to check action called from UI or another method here.
        let symbols = Thread.callStackSymbols
        let str: String = symbols[3]
        if str.contains("sendAction") == false && str.contains("SwiftUI7Binding") == false {
            print("It's called from programmatically. Abort")
            return
        }
    }

    /// We want to prevent this kind of call
    func maliciousMethod() {
        buttonClicked(UIButton())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work reliably. Compiler optimizations and, as you discovered, simply stripping the debug symbols (which happens during release builds) will break this. Checking the stack like this might work on Java/JVM, but not on most natively compiled languages.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do if someone has access to your code base, so I assume your `ViewController` is part of a binary framework to be distributed, that you want to secure against malicious programmers.  In that case, you could store the button you want to allow as a `private` or `fileprivate` property in your `ViewController`.  Then check for it in `buttonClicked()`.

So something like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var secureButton: UIButton! // <-- Added this

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Using/saving the secureButton here 
        secureButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
        ... 
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton) {
        /*
         Check for the expected sender here.  You probably don't want to 
         actually fatalError, but rather do something more sensible for 
         you app/framework
         */
        guard sender === secureButton else {
            fatalError("Strange things are afoot at the Circle-K")
        }
        ...
    }

    /// This method will now trigger the guard in buttonClicked
    func maliciousMethod() {
        buttonClicked(UIButton())
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, We're developing a SDK. We have some custom UI object classes. We want to avoid the user access to target methods without using our custom UI objects.

Comment: There are other solutions.  Since all UIKit/AppKit objects descend from `NSObject`, you could use its `attributeKeys: [String]` property to stuff some value you can check in any potential sender.  As long your SDK always sets that value.   Or you could keep a registry of valid UI objects.  There are also "associated values" (an Obj-C thing you can access from Swift: See my repo [SwizzleHelper](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwizzleHelper) for more info on that)

Comment: if you post an answer with code example I can mark as accepted.